# exclude theme from a specific container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, plone, diazo

I am making a theme for a website managed by plone using diazo and at least parts of twitter-bootstrap. Personally I'm not all too happy about that combination, but it was requested that way.
Now I was informed the other day that there will be some portlets that suppose to come in their own design, styled in an editor insinde plone (the editor seem to write the styles straight into the html). Meaning no further theming should be applied but bootstrap css recognizes the pattern and hijacks it anyway.

I tried to block that by using a form of `<notheme css:if-content=".theStaticPortlet" />` but ended up having the theme blocked on the entire site whenever a container like this was found.

Is there a way of excluding a specific container/class from being bothered by the theme while everything around it stays themed like before?

Comment: Nobody will like this, but: IFRAME

Answer (score 1):

With lesscss you can do something like that:

```
.theStaticPortlet {
    // put your specific portlet css here
}
:not(.theStaticPortlet) {
    // copy or import all your regular site css here
}
```

Comment: I thought about something similar, but .theStaticPortlet should have no css whatsoever and i can harly go through the twitter-bootstrap files and add :not(.theStaticPortlet) to every single entry. Even tho i admit that i even consider that to be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your question is purely about Bootstrap and its CSS interfering with Plone markup. Exactly which styles are being applied on your portlet? I'd bet it has to do with the DL/DT/DD tags. If so you could use Diazo to replace those with DIVs or some other neutral tags - on Bootstrap's understanding, of course.

Comment: The Problem was, that the editor allowed a completly free design of that portlets contents, so i could not know what dl/dt/dd/h1/ect would be in there and what combination of these would find a resemblance in bootstrap. Meaning i would not have known what to replace in this ever chancing type of portlet. Anyway the customer changed his opinion about various thing in the cms(yet again) eliminating at least this problem. Thanks anyway.